# Is there a Salt requisite that will execute a state only if another state has not run

Tags: salt-stack

I have a situation where I only want to execute a salt state if another state does not run.  Is that possible?

E.g.

- State1 manages file-abc
- State2 has an onchanges requisite that will only run if the file-abc changes
- State3 should only run if State2 does not execute.

The expected behavior is:

```
If file-abc changes:
   execute State2

If State2 did not execute:
   execute State3
```

The requirement here is that State3 should run if State2 doesn't, and there might be a lot of future reasons for State2 to run beyond a single file changing.

State1

```
test-state-file1:
  file.managed:
    - name: /data/test-file1
    - source: salt://foo-states/test-file
```

State2

```
test-state2-echo:
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo "Test State 2"
    - onchanges:
      - file: /data/test-file1
```

State3 - Only run if State 1 and 2 don't run.

```
test-state3-echo:
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo "Test State 3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no type of requisite that's a negative requisite for other states. The way to accomplish what you're asking (though maybe not what you want), is to use [unless](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#unless) which executes a command. Try:

```
one:
  test.succeed_without_changes

two:
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo 'hi' > /tmp/fun.txt
    - onchanges:
      - test: one

three:
  test.succeed_with_changes:
    - unless:
      - grep 'hi' /tmp/fun.txt
```

You'll see three run. Change it to

```
one:
  test.succeed_with_changes
```

And you'll see two run, but not three.

Depending on what you are really trying to accomplish, this might suit you, but it may be that there's a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: 'unless' only works if the other state ('two') leaves some sort of artifact that can be used to validate against.  What command could you put in the 'unless' if 'two' was restarting a docker service?

Is there a way for 'unless' to use the result of another state instead of executing a command?  That's really what I want but I don't see anything in the documentation to support this behavior.

Comment: @user1441126 -- *leaves some sort of artifact* -> this could be an option. Having an intermediate state to touch a file `onchanges` to state 1 and 2. Then a "third" state `unless` file exists (`ls`).